# Low USB transfer speed

Tags: usb, file-transfer, speed

I am using Windows Vista, my Motherboard is  Intel D102GGC2
The transfer speed through USB is very slow on my PC, just 2-3 MBps...

I also use Ubuntu 9.10, and surprisingly the USB transfer speed is as expected, ie 16-17 MBps.

So everytime i have to transfer Huge files i have to reboot into Ubuntu.

What might be the Problem ???
I checked the Intel website for the ubdated drivers for my mobo, but they dont support my mobo now.

Thanks

Comment: What device do you transfer data to? A pendrive? USB harddrive? Network cable?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, your Vista driver does not support Hi-Speed USB.

Answer (score 0):

eHow says configuring Vista to [Optimize for performance](http://www.ehow.com/how_5105463_increase-transfer-speed-windows-vista.html) may help: *Start > Computer > r-click USB drive > Properties > Hardware > All drives > usb drive > r-click > Properties > Performance.*

Comment: Of course one you do that, you *must* be sure to use the *Safely Remove Devices* function or else you are practically guaranteed to corrupt the drive. I think I've seen some programs that help make this easier, but they only make it easier; I don't think they flush the caches (though that could certainly be possible to implement).